# ClickHouse Join table on cluster

Tags: clickhouse

We have a ClickHouse cluster with 2 replicas and 1 shard and we have a join table on that cluster:

```
create table joinTable on cluster 'mycluster'
(
    a String,
    b String
)
engine = Join(ALL, INNER, a);
```

When we insert data to the table it goes only to one of the replicas.
we also need mutations so we can't use distributed table over the join tables.

How can we insert data to all replicas?

Is there a way to work with each replica directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it as far as I know. It's an in-memory table, so you would need to create it on every single node and manage insertion on the client side.